# Right way to store, retrieve, parse JSON object from database using sqlite3, nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, sqlite

I don't know the right way to store `JSON` object in a `sqlite` `text` field, using `nodejs` `sqlite3` driver. I did the following:
Before write it to the table I tried `JSON.stringify(jobj)`, now `jstr` value looks like `{"melicode":9876543210}`
But when I log `jstr` after select it:
`console.log(jstr) # => { melicode :9876543210}` **no double quote inside**
And, `JSON.parse(jstr)` fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things of note:

First, the result of your query is an `Object`, not a `String`. So attempting to parse it should result in an exception.

Second, Node's `console.log` does not render JavaScript objects in JSON notation. You can try that in the repl:

```
$ node
> console.log({"test": 123});
{ test: 123 }
```